# Probability throwing 16 or less with 12 dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

We've got 12 dice with the numbers 0,1,1,2,2,3 on it. What's the chance you throw 16 or less?

I've trouble calculating it because of the different probabilities of throwing 0 ($\frac{1}{6}$) or throwing 1 ($\frac{1}{3}$). It's too long to solve with a probability tree, another method could be using $(\frac{correct-outcomes}{total-outcomes})$ but I don't know how to get all the correct answers without using computer scripts.

I would like to understand the method behind the calculation so I can adjust it when we're doing different calculations with different numbers, f.e.: when throwing 10 dices, what's the chance of throwing 18 or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) (PGF) for a single die is
$$G_X(t)=\frac16+\frac13t+\frac13t^2+\frac16t^3$$
So the PGF for the sum of $12$ dice is given by
$$G_Y(t)=\Big(\frac16+\frac13t+\frac13t^2+\frac16t^3\Big)^{12}$$
You want the probability that $Y\le16$ which is given by the sum of the first $17$ coefficients of the above expansion. One can either expand the above function to read each coefficient or use the following equation to find each probability seperately.
$$P(Y=k)=\frac{G_Y^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$
Either way we have
$$P(Y\le16)=\frac{377773}{3779136} + \frac{21826079}{272097792} + \frac{666827}{11337408} + \frac{1783145}{45349632} + \frac{52010479}{2176782336} + \frac{397423}{30233088} + \frac{147719}{22674816} + \frac{524161}{181398528} + \frac{25795}{22674816} + \frac{11891}{30233088} + \frac{128161}{1088391168} + \frac{2717}{90699264} + \frac{143}{22674816} + \frac{575}{544195584} + \frac{1}{7558272} + \frac{1}{90699264} + \frac{1}{2176782336}$$
$$\boxed{P(Y\le16)=\frac{355296929}{1088391168}\approx0.3264423118}$$

Comment: You could instead compute $[t^12]\,G_y(t)/(1-t)$ by various means. That’s the generating function for the partial sums of the series represented by $G_Y$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. But, I think you meant $[t^{16}]$ as we required $Y\le16$.

Comment: Yes, $[t^{16}]$, not $[t^{12}]$.

Comment: Sorry, but can you give a link to a proof for this. i.e. that the partial sums are given by $G_X(t)/(1-t)$, I cannot find one.

Comment: It’s pretty easy to prove on your own: what series does $1/(1-t)$ represent? What do you get when you convolve it with some other series?

Comment: Yes, I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Getting an exact answer requires the use of generating functions or the equivalent, as demonstrated in Peter Foreman's answer.  However, one can get a good estimate by employing a normal approximation.  We observe that a single roll of this die has first and second moments of $3/2$ and $19/6$, respectively, so the variance is $19/6 - 9/4 = 11/12$.

Normally, I'd say $12$ rolls isn't enough for a good normal approximation, but the die's native distribution already has a normal-ish kind of shape, so $12$ is probably good enough.  We get a mean value of $12(3/2) = 18$, and a variance of $12(11/12) = 11$, and therefore a standard deviation of $\sqrt{11} \approx 3.316$.  Using a discrete approximation bins this normal approximation, so that a roll of $16$ corresponds to a value between $15.5$ and $16.5$ in the continuous approximation.  Therefore, we want the probability that a normal random variable with a mean of $18$ and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{11}$ falls below $16.5$.  This is

$$
P\left(z < \frac{16.5-18}{\sqrt{11}}\right) \approx 0.3255
$$

which is about $0.3$ percent low.

Comment: (+1) I'm surprised how accurate this is! I had to use my own code just to evaluate the probability exactly.

Comment: @PeterForeman: In fact, I had first calculated the $z$-score only to two significant digits—i.e., to $1.5/\sqrt{11} \approx 0.45$—and just by chance, the probability associated with that score is $0.3264$.  For a second, I thought it was really *really* accurate!

Comment: Love your comment "the die's native distribution already has a normal-ish kind of shape". It made me wonder how that can be characterized. Mean & variance are already accounted for, so what _else_ about the trapezoidal shape helps with convergence? Googling led to the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem): convergence goes as the "third absolute normalized moment" $E[|X/\sigma|^3]$, which might be perhaps what your intuition is about. I.e. after shifting for mean and rescaling for $\sigma$, this measure of the "shape" controls convergence to CLT.

Comment: The reason the error is so small is because the die has a symmetric distribution, so it has zero skewness. The error in the approximation of the cdf of $(S_n-n\mu)/\sigma\sqrt{n}$ by a standard normal cdf is given by the [Edgeworth series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series#The_Edgeworth_series). This has a $O(n^{-1/2})$ error term which disappears when $E[(X-\mu)^3]=0$, so the error in this case decreases like $O(n^{-1})$. @antkam

Comment: @MikeEarnest - thanks A LOT for the extra info! when the 3rd central moment $=0$, the Edgeworth series gives an $O(n^{-1})$ error while the B-E theorem I found still gives an $O(n^{-1/2})$ error.  But the Edgeworth series works for any symmetric distribution, incl. e.g. uniform, Bernoulli, etc. So this doesn't really capture Brian's comment of the die having a "normal-ish kind of shape".  Do you feel that is unimportant here?  Or are you simply saying the B-E bound is not the explanation because Edgeworth is at least a _better_ explanation?

Comment: If $X$ had zero skewness _and_ excess kurtosis, you would get $O(n^{-1.5})$, but that is [not the case here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4!*SeriesCoefficient%5Blog((1%2F6)+%2B+(1%2F3)e%5Et+%2B+(1%2F3)e%5E(2t)+%2B+(1%2F6)e%5E(3t)),%7Bt,0,4%7D%5D%2F(11%2F12)%5E2). So, the shape of $X$ is not really helping the goodness of normality approximation. @antkam

Comment: @MikeEarnest - this is really surprising.  i wonder if it's a matter of expectation (sorry!)  as in i thought this $X$ would approximate Normal well, but what i really felt is that it would approximate better than some Uniform discrete $Y$ of the same mean and variance (a "normal" die, rescaled).  and that may still be true, i.e. neither approximates Normal all that well (besides being symmetric) but at least $X$ does a better job (just a presumption).

Comment: @MikeEarnest: It seems to me that the error does have a smaller multiple than it would have if $X$ were uniformly distributed on $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, though, doesn't it?

Comment: You are right. Let $X$ be the die in OP, and let $Y\sim \text{Unif}\{0,1,2,3\}$. The fourth cumulant of $X$ is $\approx-0.94$ ([source](http://tinyurl.com/yynwkdh7)), and of $Y$ is $-1.36$ ([source](http://tinyurl.com/y5vbnmab)), so error in the normal approximation to $Y$ will be about 40% larger than that of $X$. Still, this pales in comparison to the benefit attained by symmetry alone.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Agreed in general, especially for large $n$.  However, after only $12$ rolls, the difference between $n^{-1}$ and $n^{-1.5}$ might not be big enough to dominate the benefit.  Thoughts?

Comment: @BrianTung You have a point, $n$ is small so I cannot wave away the constants with asymptotics.